# Invalid Cookie Header in IBM MobileFirst Platform

Tags: cookies, ibm-mobilefirst, ltpa

I am finishing our first IBM MobileFirst application, but since the beginning we received a warning from the HTTP Adapter about an invalid cookie header.

The exact message is:

> [WARNING ] Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie:
>   LtpaToken2=LuuZMW2JzaYtcAz2rtu5EBjKxg1obqeMXszGC5bTMGcJPcxFxO/v/l5BbKJIzZcLFF7mM1eGm+yViqy3ylxdjzdRgSpvSODGqWzZVNzOxQiBookc10mtu1RCAVxnyFTmsm9InXOwtkQV118xLHe1JeDrlcpKOvGoI/+JVG0dN/bXxbf6LqovbBbUHdCTuk7uJC3f3SOSujvde9ekgut+y2XO1PY3f1EaAFa8lHiVW2gY2Jyj+ry7FwCoVUBqUvydq+kJuhqvQiPOU94pq7knXbaZCBnH9QzcmnCRso4s8KWy58TGVo8UgU9q7OVdSt2P;
>   Path=/; HttpOnly'

The adapter only does requests to a Java backend. This happens on every call from the application to the adapter, even if the adapter itself doesn't do a request to the backend. I am not touching any cookies or headers as far as I know neither do I use LTPA. I am currently working with MobileFirst Platform 6.3.

My question is, will this happen when the adapter is online or does this only happens on my local development computer? If it still happens on the server, I really would like to solve this, but whatever I try, it won't resolve this message.

As suggested on [this website](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI33538), I need to place cookiePolicy in the connectionPolicy. I tried all the values stated on [this website](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_http_adapter_connect_pol.html) and even BEST_MATCH as I first thought it was also a possible value, but the warning always stays the same.

What can I do to remove this message or at least hide it, so I won't ever see it again.

Comment: Add background information about your project - what does it do, what are you doing in your adapter code, are you touching any cookies/headers, and whether or not you're actually using LTPA in it, your MFP full version and build number, etc..

Comment: What is your MFP 6.3 build number...

Comment: 6.3.0.00-20150130-1638

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely happening due to IBM APAR PI33538:

> SERVER SET COOKIE WARNING UPON INVOKING AN HTTP ADAPTER WHICH USES
>   DEFAULT COOKIE POLICY RATHER THAN BEST MATCH POLICY

You are using MFP 6.3.0.00-20150130-1638 which may not contain this fix.
It is recommended that you will download from IBM Fix Central the latest available iFix for MFP Studio and verify that this no longer happens.

Likewise for any QA/UAT/Pre-prod/Production environment, make sure you are using the latest available iFix installation.